# Change image src based on ng-click index AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this angularJS code, the directive template defines:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in getNum(myNum)" ng-click="toggle($index)" id=$index>
      <img src="img/{{ImgTest}}">
 </li>
```

Also, my directive code has :

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {            
        scope.ImgTest= "Img_1";
```

On an ng-click I wish to change the image on all the `<li>` elements before the one clicked from Img_1 to Img_2.  (So change all the `<li>` elements with an index between 0 and the `$index` of the one clicked).

How can this be achieved ? 
.. Thanks

Comment: Right now every `<li>` will get the same image- Img_1.  Do you want them all to change on the ng-click?  Or do you want just the image in that one `<li>` to change?  Or?

Comment: Thanks Dave for replying.. I want the image from start of the list to that list element to change

Comment: i.e. from first element of the list to that index... Any help would be highly appreciated... really stuck in here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use an `ng-switch` that is controlled by a variable I'm calling `switchPoint`,  `switchPoint` is set to `$index` by `toggle()`).

Everything before `switchPoint` will use `ImgTest` while everything after will use `ImgTest2`.

Here's the `ng-switch` code (which tests the current `$index` against `switchPoint`).

```
<div ng-switch="switchPoint < $index">
    <div ng-switch-when=true>
        <img src="img/{{ImgTest}}">
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when=false>
         <img src="img/{{ImgTest2}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an updated link function with the toggle function, and `switchPoint` variable.

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {            
     scope.ImgTest= "Img_1";
     scope.ImgTest2= "Img_2";
     scope.switchPoint = -1;
     scope.toggle= function(val) {
        scope.switchPoint= val;
    };
}
```

Here's a fiddle (that prints {{imgTest}}... instead of using an image purely for simplicity sake):  http://jsfiddle.net/ueX3r/