# How to change image Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-click="Change();"`
Function `Change()` calls AJAX function that returns param: `{'init' : 'off/on'}`
How I can cnange image `src` if `init == 'off'`.

Simply to check by condition if?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312922/change-image-src-based-on-ng-click-index-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `ng-src` directive

more info

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc